# Django ORM group by date from datetime with groups aggregation

Tags: sql, group-by, django-orm

I have one single table, where I want to do a `grouping by` first, then aggregate these groups into some values. So...

Table "**statistic**"

```
| owner_id | created_at | views | clicks | ... other numbers
```

What I want to get when I am doing this:

```
    Statistic.objects.filter(
        owner_id=X
    ).annotate(
        day=Cast('created_at', DateField())
    ).values(
        'day'
    ).annotate(
        models.Avg('views')
    )
```

... is an `list` with a data grouped by `date` casted from `created_at` (`DateTime` field) and with a aggregated values like average views or clicks etc...

Problem is that django adds `group by "statistic"."created_at"`, which is brokes my requirements. I have tried to run an raw SQL-query, but unfortunately, it's also requires grouping by created_at.

Please help me, explain why it's required to be, and how to solve my task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can truncate to the date with a [**`TruncDate`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncDate):

```
from django.db.models import Avg
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

Statistic.objects.filter(
        owner_id=X
).values(
    date=TruncDate('created_at')
).annotate(
    Avg('views')
).order_by('date')
```

Comment: You've made my day. Thanks a lot bro.